# Enable mouse scrollbar and fix vertical scrollbar in Codemirror 3.23 when direction is changed to rtl

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change my text direction based on language. Everything worked fine when it is LTR but as soon as it is switched to RTL then there are two vertical scrollbars in codemirror's textarea. When I remove the overflow-y: scroll then my mouse scroll stops working and changing directions don't add new vertical scrollbar. 
I want to fix the vertical scrollbar in right and linenumbers in left irrespective of text directions with mouse scrollbar working.

[image]

Comment: Can you post you HTML/CSS please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Top and Right property from CodeMirror-vscrollbar class as below:

```
.CodeMirror-vscrollbar { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.CodeMirror-hscrollbar {
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Create another class in Codemirror.css with following names:

```
.ltrAlign{
right: 0; top: 0;
}
.rtlAlign{
left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

Then add the following code in your jsp or php page whichever you are using:

For Left to Right:

```
$(".CodeMirror-vscrollbar").removeClass('rtlAlign');

$(".CodeMirror-vscrollbar").addClass('ltrAlign');
```

For Right to Left:

```
$(".CodeMirror-vscrollbar").addClass('rtlAlign');
$(".CodeMirror-vscrollbar").removeClass('ltrAlign');
```